# update_or_create only for first record

Tags: python, django

I want to check if multiple records are equal to IS_USABLE = False then update only one record to IS_USABLSE = True.But it fails.

```
new_invoice = N_INVOICE.objects.update_or_create(INVOICE_IS_USABLSE=False,
 defaults={'INVOICE_IS_USABLSE':True,})[0]


error:
accuont.models.MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one N_INVOICE -- it returned 3!
```

Comment: What fails? One possible hint: `update_or_create` returns a pair: `instance, created`, so usually you assign the result like: `invoice, created = model.objects.update_or_create` OR `invoice, _ = ...` if you don't care whther it was created or updated